# Track observables in combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've inherited a code base that uses combineLatest and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to track the inner observables to provide status updates to the UI as this is a long running process (i.e. greater than a few seconds).

I'm brand new to angular and rxjs - the code I'm looking at is below.

I don't think this needs to use combineLatest as all three are http requests so not returning multiple values.

Is there a better option for me to use so I can easily track the status and update the UI?

```
private vehiclesWithIssueData$() {
    let result = combineLatest(this.vehicles$, this.vehicleSpecs$, this.visInspMonData$()).pipe(
        map(w => Array.from(w[0].entries()).map(v => {
            let [vehicleId, vehicle] = v;
            let [vehicleMap, vehSpecMap, monitoringMap] = w;
            let monIssues = monitoringMap.get(vehicleId) || [];
            let spec = vehSpecMap.get(vehicle.specificationId);

            return <IDisplayVehicle>{
                serialNo: vehicle.serialNo,
                altText: monIssues.map(m => m.issueText).join("\n") || "No issues",
                application: spec?.vehicleApplication || "unknown",
                model: spec?.model || "unknown"
            };
        })),
    );
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Multiple ways. but it might become a bit cluttered code. you could add a pipe on each observable that with tap and then console.log the values coming from those streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use many RxJS helper functions such as [combineLatest](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest), [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin), and [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat), since all the inner `Observable`(s) are HTTP requests as you mentioned which will be completed directly after emitting their values.

And to track each one of the combined `Observable`(s), you can use the `tap` operator with each one of them, to enable/disable loading or whatever you need.

You can try something like the following:

```js
// import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const result = combineLatest(
  this.vehicles$.pipe(tap((vehicles) => console.log(vehicles))),
  this.vehicleSpecs$.pipe(tap((vehicleSpecs) => console.log(vehicleSpecs))),
  this.visInspMonData$().pipe(
    tap((visInspMonData) => console.log(visInspMonData))
  )
)

// ...
```

Read more about Observables & RxJS in Angular here:
https://angular.io/guide/observables

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tap operator, before your map, and there you can view your data from the stream.
As a tip, avoid using indexes when you’re using combineLatest, because it can cause problems in the future and it’s hard to maintain. (for example the data it might be chaged and your indexes will be invalidated)